# How can I create this circular non symmetrical object?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

Since there was some confusion over what I was asking yesterday, here is another try. Can someone tell me how to create the object seen below?

I have marked the object I am interested in:
[image]

Please note that the inner loop of the object is circular.

Comment: Is the other side flat?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: @moonboots Sadly the other side I have no image off. But for this try the best would be symmetrical, i.e. the other side should be the same as the one photographed. Thanks.

Comment: @Duarte the other question had gone off the rails as I had not clearly stated my intention. Maybe we should delete the other one.

Comment: No, please don't delete it. As soon as your post gets answers, or even replies it becomes as much yours has it is from the other users, forming the collective effort of all users who participated. Deleting it would prevent future users from learning from it, and negate any reputation the users may have gained. I'll allow it this time, but in the future try to better illustrate your questions

Comment: @Duarte. Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** I actually realize that your object is probably a monohedron. In that case, create a cube, stretch it on X, loopcut it:

[image]

Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier, keep the *Twist* mode, choose an angle of 90° on X:

[image]

Give it a second *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, 360° on Z:

[image]

Previous answer:

Create a circle, extrude up so that it matches your image:

[image]

Cut the inner edge with the knife tool:

[image]

Move up the vertices one but one to get the elevation:

[image]

Bevel the inner edge:

[image]

Result with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: AH, jinx! I think yours is better anyways.

Comment: well, rotating the inner edge is probably a better idea than moving the vertices one by one  ;)

Comment: except maybe it should be more like a spiral

Comment: Yeah, little 'o this, little 'o that.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try to implement your suggestions and come back to this thread when I am done.

Comment: Also, congrats on 100k, @moonboots!

Comment: Hey  ;)   thanks @BlenderMaster15

Comment: I gave moonboots answer the checkmark as it comes closest but thanks for both of your guys help!

Comment: @Paul I've edited because I think that what you want is actually a monohedron

Comment: Thanks moonboots. Looks great.

Answer (score 13):

Yay, and here's the totally spaced out Geometry Nodes version!

[image]

...just because we all love procedural spaghetti.

In this example, the object is designed to be flexible and can be changed via parameters.

[image]

1. First we create a small spiral here.

   [image]
2. Then we need a grid with three rows, whose points we bend in the next step.

   [image]
3. The upper and lower rows are adapted to a circle, and the inner row adapts to the positions of the spiral. With this we have our basic shape.

   [image]
4. This is extruded/mirrored and the vertices are merged.

   [image]
5. Finally, a few vertices are shifted a bit, depending on their proximity to the center.

   [image]

...Dish up, the noodle soup is ready!

The node group at a glance:

[image]

Here is the blend file:

[image]

> For further processing, it is recommended to simply convert the object into a mesh. Before applying a subdivision modifier, you should set the *Mean Crease* of the edges to *1*.

Comment: Wasn't it you, who called me crazy? ;-) really nice +1

Comment: Sometimes nodes feel really quite user friendly... other times I honestly wonder whether old fashioned code wouldn't have been a lot cleaner ‍️. But nice job +1

Comment: Wow. Great work quellenform. Crazy animation! ;)

Answer (score 6):

Nothing terribly complex about it, just break it down.

Start with a circle.

[image]

Inset that circle inward and offset its center.

[image]

Put  a loop cut  in between those two. Maybe offset it's center a bit too, to taste.

[image]

Rotate this edge loop a bit on the Y and X axis to give it the slant. raise it back up to elevate it above the outer ring.

[image]

Add two edge loops and do some careful vert-by-vert adjustment of their proximity to the top edge loop, to give it the fade.

[image]

Extrude down the outer edges a bit, Add a Sub-Surface modifier, maybe scale it up a touch in world-space to adjust the height. There ya go.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but i decided to finish what i started in your first question in case you or someone else likes it.

If that shape is not plane below, but instead twists like the top, it is a solid mobius strip or a 'mobius ring'. For that case, I did a Geometry Nodes to generate one based on the inner and outer circle:

[image: Dynamic Mobius Ring]
[image: Mobius Ring bottom not flat]

Before doing the Geometry Nodes, i was trying to imagine a way to get to the ring using the inner and outer circles:

[image: Mobius mesh with circles overlay]
[image: Mobius ring base circles]
[image: Mobius ring edges from base circles]
[image: Mobius ring projecting]

Geometry Nodes:

[image: Mobius Ring Geometry Nodes]

It may look complicated, but at the end is just getting points from circles and creating the mesh.

[image]